# Ansys CFX Flow UnSymmetrical

Tags: fluid, ansys

I am doing a simple ANSYS CFX simulation of airflow through the increasing cross section with no obstacles and the geometry is symmetry But the problem is that the flow is not symmetric!!

I have tried different meshing but I still have the same problem!

How can I get a symmetrical flow in the d[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o35s.jpg)uct?

Answer (score 0):

With high Reynolds numbers, the Navier Stokes equation solutions are not symmetrical anymore for flows between parallel walls, maybe that's the case in your CFD. That you gain the same results even after remeshing indicates something in this direction. Decreasing the flow velocity of your fluid could give you another hint.